# Could neutrinos be used to take high resolution pictures of atomic nuclei?

Tags: measurements, neutrinos, microscopy

Of course, this is obviously not feasible with modern technology but is it theoretically possible?

Answer (score 2):

Actually high energy neutrinos have been used in deep inelastic scattering and gave an image of the protons and neutrons. The experiments helped establish the quark model in the '60s and '70s . Here are  some [lecture notes](http://www-archive.ph.ed.ac.uk/sussp61/lectures/06_McFarland_NeutrinoInteractions/Lecutre%20Notes%20for%20Web/Web%20SUSSP%20Neutrino%20Interactions%20Lecture%20Two.pdf).

The results were expressed in [structure functions](http://inspirehep.net/record/6678?ln=en),which may be considered the equivalent of a "photograph" of a nucleon. See also [this lecture](http://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/~thomson/lectures/partIIIparticles/Handout10_2009.pdf), page 9.

Answer (score 1):

No.

The necessary ingredient for high resolution images is **high energy** (yielding short wavelengths). That's why when we need to look real close, we crank up the energy of the photons or electrons in our microscopes. (You might also call a particle collider a microscope of sorts).

Neutrinos have a very low mass and energy according to the Standard Model, equivalent to wavelengths much larger than the size of nuclei. They'd make inadequate probes to image nuclei.

Comment: but what if we accelerate them fast enough? I mean, for massless particles $E=p$, so that if $p\gg 1/R$ (with $R=$ nuclear size) we might get interesting information (about the contribution of weak interactions to the nuclear binding, for example)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Well, what if? Then we'd be in 100% speculation land. My answer tries to use existing knowledge to deduce a likely answer. Like everything in physics, the answer cannot be considered final. Your remark is intriguing nevertheless!

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform this also brings about the question about how one would go about accelerating a neutrino

Comment: One accelerates the pions or muons that give neutrinos of higher energies.